# Accesing PyQt Gui elements from another file

Tags: python, pyqt

I am learning PyQt and coming from webdesign, so excuse this question that must have very obvious answer.So I am building a PyQt application and I would like to spread methods to several files to correspond different parts of GUI. How can I access textbox locating in fileA.py from fileB.py. :

```
#fileA.py
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from gui1 import Ui_MainWindow
import fileB

class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = MyApp()
        window.show()

        #This works all fine
        def pressed():
            window.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText("Hello")


        window.pushButton.pressed.connect(pressed)


        window.button2.pressed.connect(fileB.func3)
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Now, in this file I would like to use textbox from fileA.py

```
#fileB.py
import fileA

    #How do I access window.plainTextEdit from fileA.py
def func3():
    print "hello"
    fileA.window.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText("Hello")
```

What am I doing wrong? What would be best way to spread functionality to multiple files if not this?

Thank you for taking time to read this.

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of Python's class inheritance, like so:

**fileA.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from gui1 import Ui_MainWindow
import fileB

class MyApp(fileB.MyApp, QtGui.QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
     self.MyMethod()
     # Should print 'foo'
```

**fileB.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from gui1 import Ui_MainWindow

class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow):
  def MyMethod(self):
    print 'foo'
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, first off, the code under `if __name__ == "__main__"` will *never* be run when you are importing `fileA.py`, and so `fileA.window` does not exist. That's what it should do: run only when `__name__` is `"__main__"`, i.e. run as a top-level program. Instead, you should import `fileA.py`, create the `QApplication` and `window` again, then access `window.plainTextEdit`. However, this creates a very tight coupling between the code, as you are directly accessing a widget in `MyApp` from `fileB`. It might be better if instead, you expose a method in `MyApp` that appends to the text box instead of having `fileB.py` do it directly. So you may want to think about what you want to do and how to structure your program.

Of course, you don't *have* to structure your code that way; you could simply do

```
window = MyApp()
window.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText("Hello")
```

in `fileB` if you wanted.